# A small code with tkinter do not display any window on mac

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I have a small code which i am trying to run on mac. i am using Spyder for this. My issue is no window appears on running this tkinter code.

```
from tkinter import *

class Window(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master

# initialize tkinter
root = Tk()
app = Window(root)

# set window title
root.wm_title("Tkinter window")

# show window
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: i do not get any error on running this code.

Comment: Does adding `app.grid()` or `app.pack()` at the end of 'Initialize tkinter' help?  Does adding some content to the Frame make it show?

Comment: Adding app.grid() or app.pack() has not worked. The same works perfectly when i run it through  terminal of my macbook.